# Node.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, multer, multifile-uploader

I'm just learning node.js and have difficulty to make a simple file upload using express and [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Here is the form:

Upload Image

In my `configure.js` I have:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(multer({dest:'../public/upload/temp'}).single('file'));
```

And the `image.js` controller:

```
create: function(req, res) {
        var saveImage = function() {
            console.log(req.body);
            var possible = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
                imgUrl = '';

            for(var i=0; i < 6; i+=1) {
                imgUrl += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            }

            var tempPath = req.files.file.path, //<line 55 error
                ext = path.extname(req.files.file.name).toLowerCase(),
                targetPath = path.resolve('./public/upload/' + imgUrl + ext);

            if (ext === '.png' || ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.jpeg' || ext === '.gif') {


                fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function(err) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    res.redirect('/images/' + imgUrl);
                });
            } else {
                fs.unlink(tempPath, function () {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    res.json(500, {error: 'Only image files are allowed.'});
                });
            }
        };

        saveImage();
    },
```

However I get this error when I try to upload an image:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
    at saveImage (/home/pc/node-dev/test-proj/controllers/image.js:55:37)
    at module.exports.create (/home/pc/node-dev/test-proj/controllers/image.js:76:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pc/node-dev/test-proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/pc/node-dev/test-proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/pc/node-dev/test-proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/pc/node-dev/test-proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/pc/node-dev/test-proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/pc/node-dev/test-proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/pc/node-dev/test-proj/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at urlencodedParser (/home/pc/node-dev/test-proj/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:95:37)
```

And when I log the `req` object, `file` is not there:

```
{ title: 'myimage', description: 'something' }
```

Actually the snippet is just a slightly modified version what I read in [this book](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/web-development-mongodb-and-nodejs), which is using outdated express-3. So basically I just updated it with the `multer` part.

I'm wondering what is wrong here and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you ever find a workable solution to this with multer? I tried the fix listed below, and changing it to req.file and req.path seems to work, but now the example from the book redirects to the /image/ route without successfully naming or receiving the file.

Comment: You var tempPath = req.file.path; 

var ext = path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase(); 

var targetPath = path.resolve('./public/upload/' + imgUrl + ext);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using [`upload.single`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#singlefieldname), which you should use `req.file` not `req.files`. To upload multiple files, use [`upload.array`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount).

Notice that you don't need another `.file` after `req.file`. `req.file` is the uploaded file if you are using `upload.single`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However now that I use `tempPath = req.file.file.path,` I causes  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined` error. Any ideas?

Comment: @qliq [as stated in document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#singlefieldname), you just need to use `req.file.path`, not `req.file.file.path`. ( From document: The single file will be stored in `req.file`. )

Answer (score 0):

From the same [book](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/web-development-mongodb-and-nodejs) referenced above, I was able to come up with a working solution after logging to the console the `req.files.file` and from the details in the console the `path` exists in the `file` object and it is `tempFilePath` not `path` so the actual path would be `var tempPath = req.files.file.tempFilePath;`. And the full code

```js
create: function(req, res){
    var saveImage = function(){
      var possible = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
      var imgUrl = '';

      for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
        imgUrl += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*possible.length));
      }

     // if (!req.file) return console.log('Please upload a file')
     console.log(req.files.file)
     //
      var tempPath = req.files.file.tempFilePath;
      var ext = path.extname(req.files.file.name).toLowerCase();
      var targetPath = path.resolve('./public/upload/' + imgUrl + ext);

      if(ext === '.png' || ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.jpeg' || ext === '.gif'){
        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function(err){
          if(err) throw err;

          res.redirect('/images/' +imgUrl);
        });
      } else {
        fs.unlink(tempPath, function(){
          if(err) throw err;

          res.json(500, {error: 'Only image files are allowed'});
        })
      }
    }
    saveImage();
  }
```

[The details to the console after logging the `req.files.file`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s720d.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the same book referenced above, this is 2021 and all codes above fail, I have battled with this for over 4 days and finally cracked it. I moved the multer middleware into the routes module for it to work

update routes.js to

```
    var express = require('express'),
 path = require('path'),
 router = express.Router(),
 home = require('../controllers/home'),
 image = require('../controllers/image');
 const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: path.join(__dirname,
    'public/upload/temp')});
module.exports = function(app) {
 router.get('/', home.index);
 router.get('/images/:image_id', image.index);
 router.post('/images',upload.single('image'), image.create);
 router.post('/images/:image_id/like', image.like);
 router.post('/images/:image_id/comment', image.comment);
 app.use(router);
};
```

update the create function in the image controller to

```
create: function (req, res) {
    var saveImage = function () {
      var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789",
        imgUrl = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
        imgUrl += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      }

      var tempPath = req.file.path,
        ext = path.extname(req.file.originalname).toLowerCase(),
        targetPath = path.resolve("./public/upload/" + imgUrl + ext);
      if (
        ext === ".png" ||
        ext === ".jpg" ||
        ext === ".jpeg" ||
        ext === ".gif"
      ) {
        fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function (err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.redirect("/images/" + imgUrl);
        });
      } else {
        fs.unlink(tempPath, function () {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.json(500, { error: "Only image files are allowed." });
        });
      }
    };
    saveImage();
  }
```

comment out or remove the multer middleware from the configure.js module

```
//app.use(multer({ dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload/temp')}).single('image'));
```

ensure your form  in the index.handlebars correspond to this

```
<form method="post" action="/images" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="panel-body form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="file">Browse:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" id="file">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="title">Title:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="description">Description:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="2"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" id="login-btn" class="btn btn-success" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload ">
                        </i> Upload Image</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```